# How to track the usage log of a FeatherJS gateway?

Tags: logging, microservices, feathersjs

I have created a microservice gateway with FeatherJS and I want to track usage logs. Can you please advise me on the steps to do this or recommend a library?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you want to do this manually. You can add the logs in the global [hooks](https://feathersjs.com/api/hooks#hooks) of feathers.

If you will use third party service like [datadog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/express/) then just follow the docs on how to integrate the service in express.